# '.info/connected' takes very long to respond

Tags: firebase

I get a very long wait between going offline and the '.info/connected' handler being called.

In my tests the average wait is about 30 seconds which is much too long to for example notify the user.

Is this configurable somewhere or is there any way to reduce it ?

(FB web interface on chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase client uses WebSockets to connect to its servers. The value of `.info/connected` becomes false when the underlying socket signals that it's been closed, which depends on the socket provider (Chrome in your case). There is no API in the Firebase SDK that allows you to control this.